# css, selecting the first child and last child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can somebody help me to set diferent styles to firstchild and lastchild? 
I want to set the left side of first element with round corners and the right side of last element. Middle elements without round corners...
I have created a fiddle to show my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Mqay8/

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question so people aren't forced to click in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label you're trying to style is the second child, since it comes after the input tag. Here's a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/Mqay8/4/), with the label moved into first position.

Answer (score 2):

```
div :first-child {

}

div :last-child {

}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question according to the fiddle, but to be fair, the code isn't in the question in the first place; it's behind a jsFiddle link.

Comment: Yes, just looked at the fiddle... the question could certainly be a bit clearer!